# How to download file using Angular?

Tags: angular, file, download

I have an image file which is shown in the browser. So to display the image, the browser has to send get request and download it in memory to display the image.

I also have a download image button. So when I click on it, it generates a blob and downloads it.

Using this implementation I have to download the same file two times. Once for previewing and again for downloading.

Now my question is:

> Is there a way to directly save the file to disk, from the file which is already downloaded in the browser for displaying?

Comment: You can try caching that data ,with either a cacheable library so new request wont be sent and you can download from the cache memory is that possible in your project?

Comment: @SwarupChavan For image file I can go with your solution, but my project includes videos and pdfs too. For those kind of files it won't be possible to cache such huge amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can did with anchor tag check bellow code

```
<a download href="{{url}}">Download</a>
```

Comment: This will download the file from server again and then save the file to disk.

Comment: In my code implementation I am showing preview of the image to the user. So when the user can see the image in browser, that means the file is already downloaded in temp memory of browser. So what I want is, instead of fetching the file again from the server, I want to save the file to disk directly from the temp memory of browser.